# How to integrate Gmail and Facebook with OAuth2.0 using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am new to spring boot and security, i have a requirement to integrate gmail and facebook With OAuth2.0 in Spring boot. Can anyone suggest me any refferences.

Thank you In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Spring Social once.

https://projects.spring.io/spring-social/